# Extracting DEM from PRISM data?

Tags: dem, remote-sensing, software-recommendations, jaxa

I have PRISM data which is in the following format.

Are there any ways (software and methods) to extract the DEM or elevation information from these data files?

[image: Prism files]

Comment: Yes. I worked with JAXA data and I could easily import it in QGIS. Did you try importing **IMG-ALPSMN234433460-01B2G_UN**?
If I am not mistaken it is a raster, and creating a DEM is very straightforward in QGIS. Could you provide us with the info of the summary.txt?

Comment: thanks for answering. following is the summary provided in the summary text

Comment: Odi_ProductManagementNo="A1301875"
Odi_ProductManagementBranchNo="017"
Scs_SceneID="ALPSMN234433460"
Scs_SceneShift="0"
Pds_ProductID="O1B2G_UN"
Pds_ResamplingMethod="NN"
Pds_UTM_ZoneNo="44"
Pds_MapDirection="TrueNorth"
Pds_OrbitDataPrecision="Precision"
Pds_AttitudeDataPrecision="OnSitePrecision"

Comment: Did you succeed in importing it into QGIS?

Comment: yes , i can import it. and its look black and white ortho imagery with clouds.

Comment: could you please give mail id to sent full text

Comment: In order to download the DEM provided by the Japan Aerospace Exploration Agency (JAXA) you need to fill in the form, then you will access to their DEM (If I am not mistaken 30 meters accuracy). Find the link to their webpage [here](http://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/ALOS/en/aw3d30/index.htm). Good luck